# CycleGAN with 1-channel tiffs both as input and as output

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am running CycleGAN with different types of tiffs in trainA and trainB. The tiffs are 256x256 pixels in size and have 1 channel per pixel. I am using tiffs to have a wide range of values.

I changed the code as suggested in the [pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix
repo](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix) (https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues/320 and similar), but what I got out during the training in `./checkpoints` are three-channels PNGs. Do you think it would be possible to change the code so that it goes from 1 channel tiff to 1 channel tiff with no information loss? As far as I understand, at present the code is converting the imported files to PNGs along the way. In other words: I would like my tensors to be `[256*256*int_range,1]`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the parameters --input_nc 1 --output_nc 1 during training? It will convert the number of channels from 3 to 1.